# PreparedStatement for select count

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I have a program that will count the number of records from a variety of data sources. I have the database names and table names stored in array lists called `database_names` and `table_names` respectively. I am unable to get this to run:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table_names.size(); i++) {
    String query = "select count(1) from ?.?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    stmt.setString(1, database_names.get(i));
    stmt.setString(2, table_names.get(i));
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
}
```

I get an `ORA-00903: invalid table name` error. I have set print statements to ensure that my `database_names.get(i)` and `table_names.get(i)` were printing out the right values. They were, and if I hardcode the database name and table name into my `query` string, the program is able to count the records.

How can I properly prepare my query statement so that it is of the form:

```
select count(1) from database_name.table_name
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. The [`PreparedStatement` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) says (in part) *Note: The setter methods (setShort, setString, and so on) for setting IN parameter values must specify types that are compatible with the defined SQL type of the input parameter. For instance, if the IN parameter has SQL type INTEGER, then the method setInt should be used.* there isn't a `setTableName` method.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch both my `database_name` and `table_name` are strings and I am using the `setString()` method, so shouldn't my query resolve to `select count(1) from sampleDB.sampleTable`?

Comment: No, because a tablename isn't a SQL type VARCHAR, CHAR, etc. The key issue is **SQL type**. Also, because the table is changing the query plan wouldn't be reusable. Just use a `Statement` and build the query dynamically.

Comment: One of the major uses of a prepared statement is to allow the database to create an execution plan for the text. While bind variables can be used for criteria values, they cannot be used for the tables to be accessed. That completely defeats the purpose.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ah, in that case do I run any risk of injection by changing my query to `"select count(1) from " + database_names.get(i) + "." + table_names.get(i);`?

Comment: Are those fields coming from the user? If so, yes!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle says: *When you prepare a SQL statement or PL/SQL block that contains input data to be supplied at runtime, placeholders in the SQL statement or PL/SQL block mark where data must be supplied.*

Schema and table name are not data, but data structures. During prepare phase Oracle parses statement, checks privileges. optimises plan. This is not possible without schema and tablename.
Oracle uses bind variables in execution phase, when your statement is prepared.

In your case you have to create new PreparedStatement for each table